# Does HTTP status code 400 mean I can assume authentication worked?

Tags: http, basic-authentication, http-status-code-400

If I was getting status 403 earlier, then changed something and started getting a 400, can I assume the basic auth part worked?

Answer (score 1):

400 stands for "Bad Request". So I wouldn't assume it worked.